# CSS child selector with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Can I get in jQuery the list o childs (span) that belongs to a div? I mean the number of childs. I am generating a form with a few spans, and I need to know how many spans I have generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), and the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
var numberOfSpans = $("#someId > span").length;
```

Or, if you want to use `this` for example, you can use the [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
var numberOfSpans = $(this).children("span").length;
```

Note that both of the snippets above give you the number of direct children `span` elements. They won't count further descendants. If you want to do that, you can remove the `>` character, or use `find` instead of `children`.

Comment: Thank you guys, all the solutions are perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get this by doing so:

```
$('#div-id span').size();
```

http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the number of spans

```
var count = $("div").find("span").size();
```

This gives you the children as a new jQuery object, to loop through

```
var list = []; 
list = $("div").children();
```

Comment: `children` returns another jQuery object, not an array.

Comment: an empty jQuery object looks like this: `$("")` not `[]`

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="div1">
    <span>s</span>
    <span>s</span>
    <span>s</span>
    <span>s</span>
 </div>

$(function(){
  alert($("#div1 >span").size()) 
});
```

sample program here : http://jsfiddle.net/Bhrk2/